# SQL Server 2005 next lowest date greater than today

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2005, group-by, having

I’m looking to find the next lowest date, greater than today in a select statement.
I’ve simplified the data down as an example.

Example data: `table_1`

```
name    order_no    order_date  Due_date    Run_no
customer1   abc1    01/04/2015  02/05/2015  1
customer2   def2    02/04/2015  02/05/2015  2
customer3   ghi1    03/04/2015  02/05/2015  3
customer2   def3    04/04/2015  04/05/2015  2
customer2   def4    05/04/2015  05/05/2015  2
```

and example query:

```
select 
    name,
    order_no,
    order_date,
    Due_date,
    Run_no
from 
    table_1
where 
    run_no = '2'
group by 
    name, order_no, Order_date, Due_date, Run_no
having 
    MIN(due_date) > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

so if today was 01/05/2015 i would expect the result to be:

```
name    order_no    order_date  Due_date    Run_no
customer2   def2    02/04/2015  02/05/2015  2
```

but what i actually get is:

```
name    order_no    order_date  Due_date    Run_no
customer2   def2    02/04/2015  02/05/2015  2
customer2   def3    04/04/2015  04/05/2015  2
customer2   def4    05/04/2015  05/05/2015  2
```

This has to be something to do with the Having clause doesn't it? 
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to use <a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx">ROW_NUMBER()</a> ranking function.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SQL Server 2005 you can use the `row_number` function to number rows and if you do that based on date (in the set of rows that fall after your specified starting date) it's simply a question of choosing the rows with number 1.

```
select 
    name,
    order_no,
    order_date,
    Due_date,
    Run_no    
from 
    (select 
       *, 
       rn = row_number() over (partition by name order by due_date asc) 
    from table_1
    where 
        run_no = '2' and
        Due_date > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
) t
where rn = 1;
```

The `partition by` part of the function makes it so that the the row numbers will restart from 1 for each new item (customer) in the partition so you can get the matching rows for many customers. This might not be what you want - maybe you just one single row, or maybe you want to partition by run_no and customer, your question doesn't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

why not just something like this:

```
Select top(1)
name,
order_no,
order_date,
Due_date,
Run_no
from table_1
Where run_no ='2'and MIN(due_date) > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

I don't understand why you put a group by. Add an order by order_no if needed.

Comment: cheers,
there will be multiple results, not just one, that's why i had the having clause, which in turn needs a group by.
I'm looking for all results that fit that criteria, not just the top one unfortunately

Comment: Never ever use the `top` clause without an `order by` clause, the results will be random and non-deterministic without explicit ordering.

Answer (score 0):

there seems no need of using group by. I would suggest to simply select them in ascending order. Which would show all the values meeting criteria, with the next lowest, greater than today on top.

```
select < your columns >
from table_1
Where run_no ='2' and due_date > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
order by due_date
```